# Проверка наличия выбраных файлов

Tags: c#, wpf

Как проверить выбраны ли файлы?

```
private void BrowseFilesButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var ofd = new OpenFileDialog {Multiselect = true};
            ofd.ShowDialog();
            ViewModel.ChoosenFiles = ofd.FileNames;
            FileBox.Text = $"Selected {ofd.FileNames.Length} scripts";
        }

        private void ExecFilesButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {   
            List<Script> scriptToRun = ViewModel.ChoosenFiles.Select(item => new Script(item)).ToList();

            SetProgressBar(scriptToRun.Count);
            var runner = new Runner(ViewModel.SelectedConnection);
            runner.RunQueries(scriptToRun, UpdateProgressBar());

            MessageBox.Show("ok");
        }
```

Comment: очевидно ofd.FileNames.Any()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы должны проверить, как юзер закрыл диалог: при помощи OK или как-то по-другому.

Для этого используется конструкция

```
if (ofd.ShowDialog() == true) ...
```

(сравнение с `true` нужно потому, что тип возвращаемого значения — `bool?`, а не `bool`).

Значение `true` означает, что диалог закрыт кнопкой OK, в этом случае список файлов обязан быть непуст.

В случае других возвращаемых значений (`false` или `null`) диалог был закрыт другой кнопкой (<kbd>Esc</kbd>, Cancel, <kbd>Alt+F4</kbd>, ...), и выбранных файлов нет. (Текущая реализация вроде бы никогда не возвращает `null`.)

Answer (score 1):

```
private void BrowseFilesButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (var ofd = new OpenFileDialog {Multiselect = true})
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult result = ofd.ShowDialog();
        if (result != DialogResult.OK || ofd.FileNames.Length == 0)
            return;
        ViewModel.ChoosenFiles = ofd.FileNames;
        FileBox.Text = $"Selected {ofd.FileNames.Length} scripts";
    }
}
```

Comment: DialogResult.OK - ругается wpf

Comment: Дополнил ответ, указав fully-qualified type name для DialogResult.

Использование DialogResult вместо bool? даёт куда более гибкое управление логикой.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал вот так и работает:

```
private void BrowseFilesButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var ofd = new OpenFileDialog{Multiselect = true};
        ofd.ShowDialog();
        if (ofd.FileNames.Length == 0)
            return;
        ViewModel.ChoosenFiles = ofd.FileNames;
        FileBox.Text = $"Selected {ofd.FileNames.Length} scripts";
    }

private void ExecFilesButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(ViewModel.ChoosenFiles.Length == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Choose sql files");
        }
        else
        {
            List<Script> scriptToRun = ViewModel.ChoosenFiles.Select(item => new Script(item)).ToList();

            SetProgressBar(scriptToRun.Count);
            var runner = new Runner(ViewModel.SelectedConnection);
            runner.RunQueries(scriptToRun, UpdateProgressBar());
            MessageBox.Show("ok");
        }
    }
```